# Arduino Reset via Software (every day)

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, millis, reset, watchdog

Dear Stack Exchanger's,

I want to reset my Arduino and system in every 24h for preventing frozen software and also other connectivity stuffs.

I wrote a program which connects a digital pin to reset pin of Arduino and I want to reset with that way.

For example my code :

```
unsigned long myTime; // Millis() function time value 
int timeExpected = 5000; // I want to reset it in every 5 secs for testing.
const int RESET_PIN = 2; // Reset pin's connection

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,HIGH);
    myTime = millis();
    Serial.println(myTime); // prints time since program started
     delay(1000);

   if(myTime % timeExpected == 0) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    delay(1000);
     Serial.println("RESET");
    //digitalWrite(RESET_PIN, LOW);(I just test with LED_BUILTIN Low function)
    }

  }
```

I have tried the watchdog timer but I cannot do it for 24 hours.
If you have another solution for reset in 24h please tell me and send me the related article/book/link etc. I will check and implement into my code.

UPDATE:
I have done this but it does not reset at very 5s .
Code :

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>
unsigned long myTime;
int timeExpected = 5000; 


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Setup started :");
// make a delay before enable WDT
// this delay help to complete all initial tasks
delay(2000);
wdt_enable(WDTO_2S);
}


void loop() {
    myTime = millis();
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(myTime); // prints time since program started
   if(myTime == timeExpected) {
     Serial.println("RESET");
    wdt_reset();
    }
```

Comment: You can't really use unstable software to reset itself - if it freezes, how can it execute the reset code? You'll need to either: 1) debug the software (you should do this anyway); 2) use the built-in watchdog timer to reset the arduino if your software doesn't reset the watchdog; or 3) use an external hardware timer to reset the Arduino at intervals. Solution 3) should be unnecessary if you do 1) and 2).

Comment: `wdt_reset()` resets the watchdog's timer to avoid reset of the MCU. read my answer again

Answer (score 2):

You can use the watchdog timer, but you have to change the way you measure the elapsed time. Try this code:

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>

unsigned long myTime; // Millis() function time value
unsigned long elapsedTime;
unsigned long timeExpected = 5000; // I want to reset it in every 5 secs for testing.
const int RESET_PIN = 2; // Reset pin's connection

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  myTime = millis();
  Serial.println("INIT");
  wdt_enable(WDTO_2S); //Enable wdt every two seconds

}
void loop() {

  //************RESET HANDLER********************//
  elapsedTime = millis() - myTime;
  if (elapsedTime > timeExpected) {
    Serial.print("RESET");
    while (1); //Intentionally halt the program, so the watchdog performs the reset    
  }
  //**********************************************
  //****************REST OF THE PROGRAM***********
  wdt_reset(); //Ensure one call to this function at least one time in two seconds or less
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  Serial.println(elapsedTime); // prints time since program started
  delay(1000);           
}
```

Please note that if you have multiple delays in your program, you have to ensure the call to wdt_reset() in order to prevent unwanted resets.
Personally I try not to use delays and would recommend avoid delays as much as possible. You may check out [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/xcvXUCih30Y) if you want to see how to avoid delays. If you achieve avoiding delays you can call wdt_reset() just one time at the begining of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an almost immediate full reset with watchdog by activating it 'on place'.

```
wdt_enable(WDTO_15MS); // resets the MCU after 15 milliseconds
while (true);
```

You can use millis() for timing the reset as any other timed function.